# More efficient way of pasting this filtered data

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a form with 27 checkboxes for different aircraft fleet types.  I currently have the following code sample working that essentially filters the desired fleet type into a new sheet where it will have further code ran.  Like I said, the code is doing exactly what I want, but I know there has to be a more efficient way of doing this.  Current run times vary between 41 seconds (2,775 filtered records) to 99 seconds (76,674 filtered records).  The dataset contains over 92,000 records and can grow from there.  Thanks for the input.

```
r = 2
   For i = 2 To z



Application.StatusBar = "Progress 1 of 6 - Transfering Filtered Data:  " & i & " Legs of " & z & " analyzed. (" & Format(i / z, "Percent") & ")"



        If DataSh.Cells(i, 8) = myCriteria1 Then

            LineSh.Cells(r, 1) = DataSh.Cells(i, 1)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 2) = DataSh.Cells(i, 2)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 3) = DataSh.Cells(i, 3)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 4) = DataSh.Cells(i, 4)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 5) = DataSh.Cells(i, 5)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 6) = DataSh.Cells(i, 6)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 7) = DataSh.Cells(i, 7)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 8) = DataSh.Cells(i, 8)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 9) = DataSh.Cells(i, 9)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 10) = DataSh.Cells(i, 10)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 11) = DataSh.Cells(i, 11)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 12) = DataSh.Cells(i, 12)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 13) = DataSh.Cells(i, 13)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 14) = DataSh.Cells(i, 14)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 15) = DataSh.Cells(i, 15)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 16) = DataSh.Cells(i, 16)

            r = r + 1

        End If

        If DataSh.Cells(i, 8) = myCriteria2 Then

            LineSh.Cells(r, 1) = DataSh.Cells(i, 1)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 2) = DataSh.Cells(i, 2)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 3) = DataSh.Cells(i, 3)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 4) = DataSh.Cells(i, 4)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 5) = DataSh.Cells(i, 5)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 6) = DataSh.Cells(i, 6)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 7) = DataSh.Cells(i, 7)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 8) = DataSh.Cells(i, 8)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 9) = DataSh.Cells(i, 9)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 10) = DataSh.Cells(i, 10)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 11) = DataSh.Cells(i, 11)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 12) = DataSh.Cells(i, 12)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 13) = DataSh.Cells(i, 13)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 14) = DataSh.Cells(i, 14)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 15) = DataSh.Cells(i, 15)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 16) = DataSh.Cells(i, 16)

            r = r + 1

        End If

        If DataSh.Cells(i, 8) = myCriteria3 Then

            LineSh.Cells(r, 1) = DataSh.Cells(i, 1)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 2) = DataSh.Cells(i, 2)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 3) = DataSh.Cells(i, 3)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 4) = DataSh.Cells(i, 4)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 5) = DataSh.Cells(i, 5)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 6) = DataSh.Cells(i, 6)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 7) = DataSh.Cells(i, 7)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 8) = DataSh.Cells(i, 8)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 9) = DataSh.Cells(i, 9)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 10) = DataSh.Cells(i, 10)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 11) = DataSh.Cells(i, 11)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 12) = DataSh.Cells(i, 12)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 13) = DataSh.Cells(i, 13)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 14) = DataSh.Cells(i, 14)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 15) = DataSh.Cells(i, 15)
            LineSh.Cells(r, 16) = DataSh.Cells(i, 16)

            r = r + 1

        End If
```

This code is repeated for all 27 fleet types where each fleet type is myCriteria1-27.  There are times where multiple fleets are selected

Comment: Is there a reason you're using separate `If-Statements`? The code will run faster if you switch subsequent `If-Statements` to `Else If`, or better yet, `Select Case`. Your code is checking the condition for each `If-Statement` the way it's written now instead of moving on once the condition is met.

Comment: You can also save a lot of space by writing `For j = 1 to 16: LineSh.Cells(r, j) = DataSh.Cells(i, j): Next j`.

Comment: Each of the blocks of 16 rows can be replaced with `LineSh.Cells(r, 1).Resize(1, 16) = DataSh.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 16)`

Comment: And the whole thing could be improved by using `Variant Arrays` - search that term on SO, there are lots of examples

Comment: Thanks.  Using the 'Else if' and the 'for j' reduced my large sample from 99 seconds to 50 seconds!  I will look into the Variant Arrays tomorrow.  Thanks

Comment: As a general rule, every direct interaction with the spreadsheet costs time, so keep it to the bare minimum. You should find the code running a LOT faster if you copy and paste data as an array, rather than on a cell-by-cell basis.